# Configuring test database so It doesn't clear data after tests run for a specific spec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am currently writing Rspec tests for a Rails API (Rails 4). I have a particular spec that requires a token to be persisted and reused for each test in the file.

However, after each `it` and `describe` block the database is wiped and a new token is generated.

Once all of these ten or so tests are run, the database is free to be cleaned.

### Some Context

The object, (the token), itself is generated upon the `GET` request to the end point. A second `GET` request from the same user will use the same token to return a new set of results while remembering what the user has just requested.

It's this interaction I'm trying to test.

### Question

What tools would people recommend that would provide this functionality? I need a specific object to persist in the database for

Or, how would people suggests I got about solving this?

I've been looking at way to configure the database cleaner gem, but haven't found any mention of configuring the database cleaning for specific cases like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tests should be written so that they can be run individually/in any order. That being said, keeping some object in database doesn't seem to be the best idea. What is the issue with recreating this object or each test?

Comment: Yeah, valid question. The tests are essentially for a newsfeed feature that uses cursoring. The object that's created contains a token which is a SecureRandom.hex object. The object also contains the users pervious query, entries within that query that have been edited/deleted etc.

The problem I'm trying to grapple with is every test generates a new  SecureRandom.hex object where I need to use the same one. The tests don't fail because it's set to return the latest set of results when an invalid key is sent.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you are writing integration test rather than unit tests. For unit tests make a good use of factories and stubbing, so ordering/db persistence is not required. (You can for example stub Securerandom.hex method, or force each token to have always same value)

Comment: Thanks broiSatse, that definitely put me closer to a solution. 

I'm currently using the following syntax: 

`before(:context) do
      RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope do
        @etag = double("Cursor Query", :etag => CursorQuery.last.etag)
      end
    end
`

It's working for the first set of tests, but the scope doesn't extend to the next describe block which contains the next GET request/next set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Rspec to run some code before and after all tests

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before :all do
    # create token
  end

  config.after :all do
    # delete token
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```